# How to modify Springer Article template to published version?

Tags: templates, article, documentclass-writing, springer, springernature

I want to modify [Springer Article template](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support) to a custom similar article template such as custom logo, custom Journal name and etc. But the online available latex template of Springer-related Article is not same as final published version.

How to modify Springer Article template to published version of Springer Article ([like this one](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10455-022-09853-1.pdf))?

Comment: Of course the intended way of getting an article in this style it to submit your paper to Springer and get it accepted, then they will typeset it for you. Other use cases are not really valid, and might even be considered as misleading (i.e., pretending the article is published while that is not or not yet the case).

Comment: Springer probably do not use tex for the final versions